# Boundary conditions in conforming Galerkin method for biharmonic equation

Tags: pde, finite-element, boundary-conditions

I am trying to solve simple scalar biharmonic equation using bubnov-galerkin finite element method. I am using $H^2$ conforming basis functions. I was wondering that if anyone can give me some pointers on how can I further debug my algorithm.

I proceeded by converting the strong form of equation to weak form:
\begin{align}
\Delta^2 u &= f \\
u &= g \;\;\; \text{on} \;\;\; \Gamma_D \\
\Gamma_N &= \emptyset
\end{align}

As an example problem, I am trying to solve:
\begin{align}
u &= \cos(4 \pi x) \cos(4 \pi y)
\end{align}
Boundary conditions are implemented using penalty method. The weak form is follows:

\begin{align}
a(u,v) &= L(v) \\
a(u,v) &= \sum_{\Omega_K \in \mathcal T} \int_{\Omega_K} \Delta \psi_{i} \Delta \psi_{j} + \sum_{E \in \mathcal E} \gamma \int_{E} \psi_{i} \psi_{h,j} \\
L(v) &= \sum_{\Omega_K \in \mathcal T} \int_{\Omega_K} \psi_{i} f + \sum_{E \in \mathcal E} \gamma \int_{E} \psi_{i} g\\
\end{align}

**Problem**: When I solve this equation on a square domain, my L2 error barely converges (convergence rate ~ 0.3). However, if I solve $u = \sin(4 \pi x) \sin(4 \pi y)$, I get correct convergence rates. I have tried the following things to debug my code:

- I solves the poisson equation, so replaced the first integrand with the stiffness integrand. I get correct convergence rates. I concluded from this that my penalty method implementation is right
- I am using Cartesian grid, so Jacobian lines up with expectations
- Since, my shape functions are defined in parametric ($\xi,\eta$) space, I had to work out the transformation for the laplacian. I tested this transformation on polar coordinates.

Many thanks.

Apologies. Editted.

Comment: Welcome to Scicomp.SE! You haven't actually written what's going wrong...

Comment: What's the domain you are solving on? From what you describe, I suspect it's a problem with the boundary conditions. Note that the biharmonic equation is a fourth-order equation and hence you need *two* boundary conditions. The natural boundary conditions are $\Delta u=0$ on $\Gamma_D$, so that's what your weak formulation imposes (and $u=\sin(4\pi x)\sin(4\pi y)$ presumably satisfies). Depending on the domain, this isn't valid for your other $u$ and so you get the wrong solution. In this case, you need to add the corresponding *nonhomogeneous* Neumann condition to your weak form.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been $\partial_n u = 0$.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "I am trying to solve" when you pre-define the solution, u. Is u a so-called "manufactured solution" where you substitute u into your PDE and Dirichlet BC to compute f and g and then use that f and g to solve the FE equations?

Comment: @ChristianClason: My domain is $[0 \times 1]^2$. ahh may be that's where I am going wrong. However, I thought that since I am solving dirichlet problem, I won't need to add the neumann boundary integrand?

Comment: @BillGreene In order to debug my algorithm, I am trying to reproduce a known solution. So, to rephrase it, given f and g, will my algorithm correctly calculate u? If it doesn't (and in my case it doesn't), then there is something fundamentally wrong with my implementation/maths/understanding.

Comment: @user21674: Only if it's zero (in which case the corresponding term vanishes). What you describe holds for the Poisson equation (or second-order elliptic problems in general), but you're not solving the Poisson equation...

Comment: yeah, that makes sense. I will try to implement this boundary condition and hopefully everything should work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Christian Clason that your problem is likely with the boundary conditions.
$\partial_n u$ is another essential boundary condition (like $u$)  so, in general, you
will also need to use your penalty approach to satisfy it. Apparently, the prescribed
$\partial_n u$ for your $u=\sin(4\pi x)\sin(4\pi y)$ case is consistent with the zero natural boundary
conditions that you are getting by default from the weak form.